# How to write the best code for data aggregation?

Tags: stata

I have the following dataset (individual level data):

```
pid  year state income
1    2000  il    100
2    2000  ms    200
3    2000  al     30
4    2000  dc    400
5    2000  ri    205
1    2001  il    120
2    2001  ms    230
3    2001  al     50
4    2001  dc    400
5    2001  ri    235
.........etc.......
```

I need to estimate average income for each state in each year `and` create a new dataset that would look like this:

```
state   year   average_income
ar      2000      150
ar      2001      200
ar      2002      250
il      2000      150
il      2001      160
il      2002      160
...........etc...............
```

I already have a code that runs perfectly fine (I have two loops). However, I would like to know is there any better way in Stata like sql style query?

Comment: There is a similar question in the database. Nick's answer is the shortest: what you want to do is exactly what `collapse` does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This shouldn't need 2 loops, or any for that matter. There are in fact more efficient ways to do this. When you are repeating an operation on many groups, the `bysort` command is useful:

```
bysort year state: egen average_income = mean(income)
```

You also don't have to create a new dataset, you can just prune this one and save it. Start by only keeping the variables you want (state, year and average_income) and get rid of duplicates:

```
keep state year average_income
duplicates drop
save "mynewdataset.dta"
```

Answer (score 11):

This is shorter code than any suggested so far:

```
  collapse average_income=income, by(state year)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the SQL tag on the question.  This is a basic aggregation query in SQL:

```
select state, year, avg(income) as average_income
from t
group by state, year;
```

To put this in a table, depends on your database.  One of the following typically works:

```
create table NewTable as
    select state, year, avg(income) as average_income
    from t
    group by state, year;
```

Or:

```
select state, year, avg(income) as average_income
into NewTable
from t
group by state, year;
```

Comment: Thank You +1. I do know how to do this using SAS, Oracle etc. I need however to do it using `Stata`. So is there any `sql` or `sql like` commands in Stata?

Comment: @Buras . . . Why did you tag it with the SQL tag if you do not need such a solution?

Comment: That was added by a different editor due to his request for SQL-like commands